# Iframe with absolute positioning + scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

The bases of the site is iframes, of which only 1 shows at a time. My problem is with the iframes not scrolling, which is a problem of absolute position. I've tried wrapping each iframe in its own absolute div, and a few overflow styles. If the iframe is styled with relative, scrolling functionality works but the format is incorrect. Weirdly, the 6th iframe scrolls perfectly Here is the full file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        position: relative;
      }

      #container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
        height: 100vh;
      }

      #left-column,
      #right-column {
        text-align: center;
      }

      #left-column {
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #ddd;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: width 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      }

      #left-column:hover {
        width: 25%;
        background-color: rgb(50, 46, 46);
        color: #fff;
      }

      #left-column nav {
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
      }

      #left-column ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      #left-column li {
        height: fit-content;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: font-size 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease; /* Adjusted transition properties */
      }

      #left-column li:hover {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: rgb(140, 142, 148);
      }

      #middle-section {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 60%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        transition: width 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      }

      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        border: none;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute; /* Use absolute positioning for iframes */
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      iframe.show {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      /* Additional style to make the iframe container responsive */
      #middle-section iframe {
        display: block;
      }

      #right-column {
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #ddd;
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: width 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
      }

      #right-column:hover {
        width: 25%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="left-column">
        <!-- Content for the left column -->
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li onclick="showIframe(1)">Fall Prep Coaches</li>
            <li onclick="showIframe(2)">Team Real Speed</li>
            <li onclick="showIframe(3)">Real Speed Staff</li>
            <li onclick="showIframe(4)">Small Group Training</li>
            <li onclick="showIframe(5)">Off-Ice Training</li>
            <li onclick="showIframe(6)">Tryouts</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div id="middle-section">
        <!-- Content for the middle section -->
        <iframe
          id="iframe1"
          class="show"
          src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/"
          scrolling="yes"
          frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
        <iframe
          id="iframe2"
          src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/RealSpeed2/index2.html"
          scrolling="yes"
          frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
        <iframe
          id="iframe3"
          src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/RealSpeed/index.html"
          scrolling="yes"
          frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
        <iframe
          id="iframe4"
          src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/SGT/index.html"
          scrolling="yes"
          frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
        <iframe
          id="iframe5"
          src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/Training/index.html"
          scrolling="yes"
          frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
        <iframe
          id="iframe6"
          src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/tryout/index.html"
          scrolling="yes"
          frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
      </div>

      <div id="right-column">
        <!-- Content for the right column -->
        <h2>Right Column</h2>
        <p>Your content goes here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      function showIframe(index) {
        document.querySelectorAll("iframe").forEach((iframe) => {
          iframe.classList.remove("show");
        });

        document.getElementById(`iframe${index}`).classList.add("show");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="middle-section">
<!-- Content for the middle section -->
<iframe id="iframe6" src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/tryout/index.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe5" src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/Training/index.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe4" src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/SGT/index.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe3" src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/RealSpeed/index.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2" src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/RealSpeed2/index2.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe1" class="show" src="https://nefphlcoaches.eu/" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Note the above code will allow scrolling on iframe1 (in accordance with order).

In general, toggle the iframes visability with display property.

None of those other iframes (2-6) should be displayed when viewing iframe1.